# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to associate an image with a string for my menu tableview among other things, but I keep getting the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int`

Code:

```
var menuItems:[String:String] = ["image1":"Order", "image2":"Notifications", "image3":"Free orders", "image4":"Payment", "image5":"Help", "image6":"Settings"]
```

In `cellForRow`:

```
cell.pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuItems[indexPath.row][0])
cell.pageName.text = menuItems[indexPath.row][1]
```

Comment: A dictionary doesn't count as an array. The items inside a dictionary will always be random order. So if you want to get items out of your dictionary, you have to either loop the dictionary or get each item by it's key

Comment: I'm not really following what you'd like to achieve. could you elaborate it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code,

```
var menuItems:[String:String] = ["image1":"Order", "image2":"Notifications", "image3":"Free orders", "image4":"Payment", "image5":"Help", "image6":"Settings"]
```

`menuItems` is a `Dictionary`. Since it is a `dictionary`, the items in it will be **unordered**. So, whenever you try to get an element from it based on `indexPath`, you might get different result each time.

**Reason for error**:

Also, since it is a `Dictionary` of type `[String:String]`, you definitely cannot get the elements from it using an `Int`, i.e. `indexPath.row` as the `subscript`. That's the reason you're getting the error.

**Solution:**

Instead, you must create a separate type - `class/struct` to store a single `menuItem`.

```
struct MenuItem {
    let pageIcon: String
    let pageName: String
}
```

Now, the `menuItems` `array` will be of type `[MenuItem]`,

```
var menuItems = [MenuItem]()
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image1", pageName: "Order"))
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image2", pageName: "Notifications"))
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image3", pageName: "Free orders"))
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image4", pageName: "Payment"))
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image5", pageName: "Help"))
menuItems.append(MenuItem(pageIcon: "image6", pageName: "Settings"))
```

`menuItems` will contain the `MenuItem` objects containing the required data. Use `menuItems` as `dataSource` of `tableView`.

Now, in `tableView(_: cellForRow:)`, you can get the `menuItem` like,

```
cell.pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuItems[indexPath.row].pageIcon)
cell.pageName.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].pageName
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you cannot subscript the dictionary with a type that is different than that of the dictionary's `key` type, which is a `String` in your case, and that means you can only subscript using a `String` value:

```
let pageName = menuItems["image1"] // This will return "Order"
```

I'm not sure what your exact use-case is, but I'm presuming that this is what you're trying to do:-

1) Make arrays of your image names and page names:

```
let yourImageNamesArray = Array(menuItems.keys)
let yourPageNamesArray = Array(menuItems.values)
```

2) In your `cellForRow`:

```
cell.pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: yourImageNamesArray[indexPath.row])
cell.pageName.text = yourPageNamesArray[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

`menuItems` is a dictionary with `String` keys and `String` values.

You must access its elements only with a `String` like this:

`let menuItem = menuItems["image\(indexPath.row)"]`

Answer (score 0):

**Do not mix up arrays and dictionary!**

Here you are using a dictionary, which means that the elements are accessible using their keys. For example the value of `menuItems["image1"]` is "Order".

On the other hand, an array element is accessible by its index.

So in your case you should use an array and access the values with their index like this:

```swift
var menuItems: [String] = ["Order", "Notifications", "Free orders", "Payment", "Help", "Settings"]
cell.pageName.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

menuItems is dictionary you need access with key value like

```
    cell.pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuItems["image\(indexPath.row)"])
    cell.pageName.text = menuItems["image\(indexPath.row)"]
```

instead of using dictionary you can directly use String array like

```
    var menuItems:[String] = ["Order", "Notifications", "Free orders", "Payment", "Help", "Settings"]
```

In tableview cell you can access like

```
   cell.pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuItems[indexPath.row])
   cell.pageName.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
```